# how did they get my credit card

Tags: account-security

I recently went on to the Dr Squatch website to buy some soap that I've been seeing in all of those Youtube video ads.  What happened really freaked me out.

The website asked for my email, and I provided my outlook account. Immediately, my cell phone buzzed with the text message sound and the website asked me for a six digit code that was texted to me. As soon as I put the code in, my address and credit card information appeared on the screen.

The phone number I had provided to outlook as a recovery option. I am dismayed that they would give it out to a third party like that. However, the credit card and address I never gave to outlook, so how could they have gotten it? Do they isntall spyware on people's computers?

Comment: Obviously they didn't get it from Outlook.com. Could it be that your browser autocompleted the form after you typed in the email address?

Comment: "information appeared on the screen" -- was it in an entry form or was it on a page that you could not change?

Comment: @schroeder It was on the page that I could not change.  The last four digits were visible, and matched, and the first 12 were just asterisks. The address I couldn't change.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I was using firefox. I have my settings that it doesn't store things, at least that's what I thought the settings were supposed to mean.